# What should be the sequence of reading(happening) Puranas?

Tags: puranas

There being numerous *Puranas*, what should be the sequence of reading adheard, to make the history more understandable to human mind.

I will also like the sequence on basis of time, for example, *Ramayan* was of time before *Mahabharat*, so its likely to make linearity in time phase, I should read *Ramayan* afterwards *Mahabharat*.

**Bottom Note :**
I know, all Puranas are dependent and can be read without the knowledge of others, but to frame a time-mass linearity, what would be the sequence, in other words, which purana happened when.(To be concies.)

Answer (score 6):

There exists hardly any reading sequences of the *puranas*. One can start with the one he likes. It is because all the eighteen major *puranas* briefly or broadly deal certain similar contents (creation, dissolution, lineage, etc.) and describe past events taking into account a central deity of the Trimurti. So a single purana can be found narrating tales of both Rama and Krishna and events of *Satya*, *Treatya* and *Dwapara yuga* along with certain nature of the age of Kali. Some also describe future events. But all the *puranas* are considered to be the creations of Vedavyasa. Hence, their literal creation times are probably same and limited to the Dwapara Yuga.

It is the literature of *itihasa*(history) that are associated with different time periods. For example, Ramayana is associated with *Tretaya yuga* and Mahabharata is of the *Dwapara Yuga*. But if you need a particular **sequential order of the *puranas* from the oldest to newest**, then it would be something like below as described in the Vishnu Purana:

> *asṭādaśa purāṇāni purāṇajñāḥ pracakṣate
>
>   brāhma pāhma vaiṣṇavañca śaivaṃ bhāgavataṃ tathā
>
>   athānyannāradīyañca mārkaṇḍeyañca saptamam
>
>   āgra yamaṣmarañceva bhaviṣyaṃ navamaṃ tathā
>
>   daśamaṃ brahmavairtaṃ laiṅgamekādaśaṃ smṛtam
>
>   vārāhaṃ drādaśañca ve skāndañcātra trayodaśam
>
>   caturdaśaṃ vāmanañca kaurmaṃ pañcadaśaṃ smṛtam
>
>   mātsyañca gāruḍa़ñcavai brahmāṇḍañca tataḥ parama*  [VP - 3.6.20-23]
>
> **The Order**:
>   1. Brahma Purana
>   2. Padma Purana
>   3. Vishnu Purana
>   4. Shiva Purana
>   5. Bhagavata Purana
>   6. Narada Purana
>   7. Markandeya Purana
>   8. Agni Purana
>   9. Bhavisya Purana
>   10. Brahmavaivarta Purana
>   11. Linga Purana
>   12. Varaha Purana
>   13. Skanda Purana
>   14. Vamana Purana
>   15. Kurma Purana
>   16. Mastya Purana
>   17. Garuda Purana
>   18. Brahmanda Purana

Comment: How did the author of Vishnu Purana know about the latter ones? Weren't they narrated in different eras by different Rishis ??

Comment: All Puranas are written by Ved-Vyas who is one of the Immortals and has the vision of past, present and future so he would presumably know what's coming in the next Kalpa.