# Can somebody provide list of Hindu texts chronologically?

Tags: scripture

Can somebody provide a list of Hindu Vedas, Purana, Up-Puranas, Upnishads, etc in a chronological manner and also provide their creation dates (if they could be dated by any means)?

Comment: I think this is too broad for the site

Comment: I don't think major books of Hinduism are more than 100. And just listing the names in chronological order along with dates (such as 3000 BC, etc) should not be a too broad answer.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that listing them by their accurate creation dates i.e. the dates when they were put down into writing, would be hard because they are hardly known. But modern researchers may have made some chronology, but that too are not accurate and only waving the stick in the dark. For example, Rig Veda is said to be composed from 1500–1200 BCE  by some and some others believe it to be 1700–1100 BCE. Similarly Samaveda is said to be 
from around 1700BCE and Yajur from 1200–1000 BCE.

> Rigveda, 1500 – 1100 BCE
>   Samaveda, 1500 - 500 BCE
>   Yajurveda, 1500 - 500 BCE
>   Atharvaveda, 1500 - 500 BCE
>   Upanishads, 1200 - 500 BCE
>   Bhagavad Gita, 500 BCE - 200 BCE 
>   Ramayana, 400 BCE - 400 CE
>   Mahabharata, 400 BCE - 400 CE
>   Mimamsa Sutra, 300-200 BCE
>   Arthashastra, 400 BCE - 200 CE
>   Nyaya Sutra, 2nd century BCE
>   Vaiseshika Sutra, 2nd century BCE
>   Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, 100 BCE - 500 CE
>   Puranas, 3rd - 16th century CE
>   Shiva Sutras, 8th century CE
>   Abhinavabharati, 950 - 1020 CE
>   Yoga Vasistha, 10th - 14th century CE

(you can view [wikipeida page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts) for the list of their research source).

So no researcher or scholar actually knows their accurate creation dates. So they cannot be trusted completely. I don't mean to say they are wrong, just that they might not be accurate to be trustworthy completely. I am no researcher or expert, so only sharing here what I know from scriptures about their order so that it may be useful.

Please see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2929/38)  for the chronology of the 18 major *puranas* as mentioned in the Vishnu Purana. But it doesn't mentions the exact date of creation, only their sequence. Similarly, the Muktika Upanishad [from verse 30 to 40] lists a sequence of 108 upanishads as below without their date of creation:

1. Isa
2. Kena
3. Katha
4. Prasna
5. Munda
6. Mandukya
7. Taittiri
8. Aitareya
9. Chandogya
10. Brihadaranyaka
11. Brahma
12. Kaivalya
13. Jabala
14. Svetasva
15. Hamsa
16. Aruni
17. Garbha
18. Narayana
19. Paramahamsa
20. Amritabindu
21. Amritanada
22. Atahrvasirah
23. Atharvasikha
24. Maitrayini
25. Kaushitakibrahmana
26. Brihajjabala
27. Nrisimhatapini
28. Kalagnirudra
29. Maitreya
30. Subala
31. Kshurika
32. Mantrika
33. Sarvasara
34. Niralamba
35. Sukarahasya
36. Vajrasuchika
37. Tejobindu
38. Nadabindu
39. Dhyanabindu
40. Brahmavidya
41. Yogatattva
42. Atmabodha
43. Naradaparivrajaka
44. Trisikhi
45. Sita
46. Yogachudamani
47. Nirvana
48. Mandalabrahmana
49. Dakshinamurti
50. Sarabha
51. Skanda
52. Tripadvibhuti-Mahanarayana
53. Advayataraka
54. Ramarahasya
55. Ramatapani
56. Vasudeva
57. Mudgala
58. Sandilya
59. Paingala
60. Bhiksu
61. Mahat
62. Sariraka
63. Yogasikha
64. Turiyatita
65. Sannyasa
66. Paramahamsaparivrajaka
67. Akshamalika
68. Avyakta
69. Ekakshara
70. Annapurna
71. Surya
72. Akshi
73. Adhyatma
74. Kundika
75. Savitri
76. Atma
77. Pasupata
78. Parabrahma
79. Avadhutaka
80. Tripuratapini
81. Devi
82. Tripura
83. Katharudra
84. Bhavana
85. Rudrahridaya
86. Yoga-kundali
87. Bhasma
88. Rudraksha
89. Ganapati
90. Darsana
91. Tarasara
92. Mahavakya
93. Panchabrahma
94. Pranagnihotra
95. Gopalatapini
96. Krishna
97. Yajnavalkya
98. Varaha
99. Satyayani
100. Hayagriva
101. Dattatreya
102. Garuda
103. Kalisamtarana
104. Jabali
105. Saubhagyalakshmi
106. Sarasvatirahasya
107. Bahvricha
108. Muktika

And regarding *upapuranas* I don't know any order. Sharing the order of *puranas* again here for ease of reference:

1. Brahma Purana
2. Padma Purana
3. Vishnu Purana
4. Shiva Purana
5. Bhagavata Purana
6. Narada Purana
7. Markandeya Purana
8. Agni Purana
9. Bhavisya Purana
10. Brahmavaivarta Purana
11. Linga Purana
12. Varaha Purana
13. Skanda Purana
14. Vamana Purana
15. Kurma Purana
16. Mastya Purana
17. Garuda Purana
18. Brahmanda Purana

**Update:**
I didn't notice you said etc. in your question. If you meant a list off all Hindu texts, not just the spiritual ones, then that would be too broad. But, [this wikipeida page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_historic_Indian_texts) will be helpful for you.

Comment: 1. Vedas are older than the dates listed. The RgVeda was once dates as being >8000 years old. Latest research on Rama Setu should tell us that Vedas are older than 1.7 million years 2. Which also dates the Ramayana to >1.7 million years 3. Yoga Vasishta was written by Valmiki which again dates it much before the dates you cite  4. These are only a few examples and Wikipedia is not always the most accurate source.

Comment: Dear @moonstar2001, thank you for the comment. But I am already aware of the inaccurate dating of the modern researchers. Hence I mentioned that too in the post (did you read?). And because I am no researcher, I didn't give any guesstimates without any reference. Only shared what I knew. If you have done some research and have proper sources and proofs, please feel free to  cite them and update the Wikipedia pages. That would be so nice and helpful!

Comment: I understand @jabahar. But don't you think we do a disservice ( to the SE and the questioner and the body of knowledge when we post an answer that we know inaccurate, disclaimers notwithstanding?

Comment: @moonstar2001 haha....yes. You are right. But what can we do? There are no real researchers here and even the so called researchers and experts accept those datings. But I want to clear the confusion if any, that these are dates believed to be when they were put into writing, not the date of their first coming into existence.

Comment: Writing on palm leaves existed way before those dates. So even by that count, the dates are inaccurate.

Comment: @moonstar2001 yes...yes my friend i know. What do you want me to do, sue the researchers? :D

Comment: I think we should not provide such answers we know are incorrect.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Incorrect or not, those datings are from researchers and accepted by scholars. So they are the standard ones. Only when we can prove them wrong by our own researches that we can say they are incorrect. Until then... glory to the almighty God, cause of and solution to all our delusions. :D

Comment: They have already been proven wrong by other researchers and scholars who dated the Rama Setu.

Comment: Please remove the year, as they are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

All dates regarding the chronological order of texts (including scripture) is western academic conjecture. The Brihadaranyaka Upanishad says in numerous places, and this is only one place (IV. v. 11.) - "As from a fire kindled with wet fuel various [kinds of] smoke issue forth, even so, my dear, the Rig-Veda, the Yajur-Veda, the Sama-Veda, the Atharvangirasa, history (itihasa), mythology (purana), the arts (vidya), Upanishads, verses (slokas), aphorisms (sutras), elucidations (anuvyakhyanas), explanations (vyakhyanas), sacrifices, oblations in the fire, food, drink, this world, the next world, and all beings are all [like] the breath of this infinite Reality. From this [Supreme Self] are all these, indeed, breathed forth."

Also VI. v. 1-4.

All were breathed forth from Brahman at the same time.

Comment: So, are you saying that The Brahman created all the Scriptures at the time of the creation of universe?

Comment: Not me. The Upanishads say. What was "breathed forth" from Brahman was breathed forth at one and the same time. Now, that does not mean that the stories being related in scripture did not occur. The gods, saints, and sages still lived and still said the words they said in the various scriptures. In one of the Puranas Vishnu in his Boar incarnation says to goddess Earth 'Every time I carry you this way...'. Vivekananda said 'An infinite number of times this has been, and an infinite number of times this will be repeated...even the combination of physical forms is eternally repeated.'